# Does "EntityStreamException: Entity stream truncation" simply mean client timeout?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-http, playframework-2.6

Since upgrading to Play 2.6, I'm seeing a lot of "EntityStreamException: Entity stream truncation" in our logs. It looks to strongly correlate with a client timeout, which is not alarming. It is a little alarming to have an Exception bubble up to application code for this common HTTP occurrence, so I'm worried it's more than just a client timeout.

```
akka.http.scaladsl.model.EntityStreamException: Entity stream truncation
    at akka.http.impl.engine.parsing.HttpMessageParser$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(HttpMessageParser.scala:321)
    at akka.http.impl.engine.parsing.HttpMessageParser$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(HttpMessageParser.scala:319)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.Collect$$anon$6.$anonfun$wrappedPf$1(Ops.scala:217)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.SupervisedGraphStageLogic.withSupervision(Ops.scala:178)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.Collect$$anon$6.onPush(Ops.scala:219)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:515)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:478)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:374)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:474)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:563)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:730)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:745)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:655)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm getting the same messages with Play 2.7

Comment: never did, i just stopped logging it. which is a bummer if this message represents a real problem.